# Unit testing angular ng-resource

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-runner, angularjs-resource

Hi i'm currently setting up some unit test with karma and jasmine. And i'm having difficulties trying to fully test an ng-resource. When i do an scope.clients.query() is executes a request. But when i try to do this in an unit test this will fail.

Does somebody have similar issues and does somebody have an idea how to resolve this problem?

e.g.

```
var mockResponse = [[{
      "name": "foo",
    },{
      "name": "foo",
    }
  ];
describe("adserver module", function() {

  //define module
  beforeEach(module('someModule'));

  describe("some controller", function() {

    var scope, controller, $httpBackend;

    var CTRL = 'someCtrl';

    beforeEach(inject(function(_$httpBackend_, $rootScope, $controller) {
      $httpBackend = _$httpBackend_;
      scope = $rootScope.$new();
      controller = $controller;
    }));

    afterEach(function() {
      $httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingExpectation();
      $httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingRequest();
    });

    beforeEach(function() {
      //define requests and responses
      $httpBackend.expectGET('/api/clients').respond(mockResponse);

      //aplly controller
      controller(CTRL, {
        $scope: scope
      });

      // flush all request
      $httpBackend.flush();
    });

    //SPECS
      it('should contain clients', function() {
      expect(typeof scope.clients).toBe('object');
      expect(scope.clients.length).toBe(2);
    });

    it('scope should re-request', function() {
      scope.clients.query();  /// will not work methode undefined
      expect(scope.clients.length).toBe(2);
    });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not using $httpBackend correctly.

First, the definition of the mock response:

```
$httpBackend.whenGET('/api/clients').respond(mockResponse);
```

Then, later, the expectation:

```
$httpBackend.expectGET('/api/clients');
$httpBackend.flush();
```